# Creating multiple namespaces using Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create multiple namespaces from a json blob input file like below:

my tfvars.json file

```
{
    "example1" : [
        {
            "namespace_name" : "test-1", 
            "team_name" : "test",  
        },
        {
            "namespace_name" : "test-2", 
            "team_name" : "test2", 
        }
   ]
}
```

My main.tf file looks as below:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "aks_namespace" {
    metadata {
      annotations = {
        name = var.namespace_name
      }
      labels = {
        name = var.team_name
      }
      name = var.namespace_name
      }
}
```

I have tried almost all the options available like for_each and dynamic.. nothing seems to be working to create the namespaces in loop.
Just wondering if this is really possible..
Unfortunately, I am not supposed to change the input .json format..
Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with all possibilities using your details but as the example1 is a tuple value , declaring it in `for_each` will error out creating namespace.

So , as a solution I declared variable example1 in `terraform.tfvars.json` as below:

```
{    "example1" : [
    [
            "test-1", 
            "test"
         ],
        [
         "test-2", 
        "test2" 
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is the `main.tf` I am using:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.5.0"
    }
  }
}
variable "example1" {
  
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  # Configuration options
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "aks_namespace" {
  for_each = {for i,v in var.example1: i=>v}
metadata {
  annotations = {
    name = each.value[0]
  }
  labels = {
    name = each.value[1]
  }
  name = each.value[0]
}
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

---

**Update:**
`terraform.tfvars.json`

```
{
    "example1" : [
        {
            "namespace_name" : "test-1", 
            "team_name" : "test"
        },
        {
            "namespace_name" : "test-2", 
            "team_name" : "test2"
        }
   ]
}
```

`main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.5.0"
    }
  }
}
variable "example1" {
  type = list(object({
    namespace_name = string
    team_name = string
  }))
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  # Configuration options
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "aks_namespace" {
  for_each = {for i,v in var.example1: i=>v}
metadata {
  annotations = {
    name = var.example1[each.key].namespace_name
  }
  labels = {
    name = var.example1[each.key].team_name
  }
  name = var.example1[each.key].namespace_name
}
}
```

Comment: thank you Ansuman for the efforts.. I was able to get this done using count and jsondecode.. However, I am still wondering if there is a way out using for_each without changing the input file..

Comment: @dils_pk, was able to achieve your requirement without changing the input file and using the code provided in update section .

Comment: This is perfect!! It works like a charm.. 
Thank you for your support..

Comment: @dils_pk, Glad to be of Help!!

Comment: Hi Again.. I am running through issue again.. not sure if I need to create a new post.. but thought you might have an answer to it.. 
Though we are using for_each here, I noticed that there is indexing while creating the objects.. This will make it challenging as similar to count meta-argument.. Unfortunately, I am not able to add or delete objects in the input file in between which causes replacement of namespaces.. Was wondering if there is a way where we could avoid indexing here and use a naming convention like app1 for 1st namespace and app2 for second namespace ..

Comment: # kubernetes_namespace.aks_namespace["2"]
Can it be replaced with :
 # kubernetes_namespace.aks_namespace["app1"]

Comment: Nevermind.. I got that working too.. Was able to remove indexing and use name.. Now the resources can be added and deleted, hence no recreation of namespace.. :)